# JCEF doesn't load page due to OAuth error

Tags: java, javafx, oauth-2.0, oauth, chromium-embedded

Please tell me, I decided to try the JCEF browser in my javafx program, I implemented a minimal example:

```
CefAppBuilder builder = new CefAppBuilder();
builder.setInstallDir(new File("jcef-bundle")); //Default
builder.setProgressHandler(new ConsoleProgressHandler()); //Default
try {app = builder.build();} 
catch (IOException | UnsupportedPlatformException | InterruptedException | CefInitializationException e) {throw new RuntimeException(e);}
client = app.createClient();
browser = client.createBrowser("https://www.google.com/", false, false);
```

I have Windows 7, so I use jcef maven 2022 (version 108.4.13), since the latest version does not run on Windows 7
The problem is that not a single site opens, not even localhost, but gives the following error:

```
[1011/224739.873:WARNING:account_consistency_mode_manager.cc(70)] Desktop Identity Consistency cannot be enabled as no OAuth client ID and client secret have been configured.
[1011/224740.180:INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Error with Permissions-Policy header: Origin trial controlled feature not enabled: 'unload'.", source:  (0)
```

Tried to run the example https://github.com/jcefmaven/jcefsampleapp and it works well, but why doesn't it work in my javafx application?

Does anyone know how to solve the problem?

Comment: That is a warning, then info, not an error, the reason your page isn't loading could be due to some other reason entirely.

Comment: Your code doesn't look like the code in the working sample app you referred to.  My advice: run the jcefsampleapp unchanged on a Java runtime that uses JavaFX (e.g. Azul Zulu JRE FX).   Then modify the sample app to launch a JavaFX application and display a website in a JCEF component displayed in a JFXPanel (according to [JavaFX/Swing integration](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/embed-swing.htm)).  Or use JavaFX WebView instead of JCEF.

Comment: I don't know JCEF at all, so this info might be wrong or misleading.  But, if you want to enable Chromium to use Google APIs (which I think is what it is trying to do when it complains about the missing OAuth client ID and secret), then you may be able to acquire and provide them by following the [Chromium API key instructions](https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/api-keys/).  BTW, this is the [source of your warning](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/chrome/browser/signin/account_consistency_mode_manager.cc#73).